# how to use jquery hiding two fields

Tags: javascript

This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(value){
  if(value=='show') { document.getElementById('busblock').style.display='block'; }
               else { document.getElementById('busblock').style.display='none'; }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function toggle(value){
  if(value=='show') { document.getElementById('guyblock').style.display='block'; }
           else { document.getElementById('guyblock').style.display='none'; }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="http://qa.onlinelabtests.com/guestlist.php" method="post">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br />
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br />
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" /> <br />
Gender: <br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" onclick="toggle('show');">&nbsp;&nbsp;Male <br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" onclick="toggle('hide');">&nbsp;&nbsp;Female <br />

<div id="guyblock" style="display:none">
Referred By
<select name="tke">
<option value="915">Cameron</option>
<option value="930">Edgar</option>
<option value="950">JD</option>
<option value="1010">Estaban</option>
</select>
</div>

<div>
Bus Transportation <br />
<input name="bus" type="radio" value="yes" onclick="toggle('show');"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Yes<br />
<input name="bus" type="radio" value="no" onclick="toggle('hide');">&nbsp;&nbsp;No<br />
</div>

<div id="busblock" style="display:none">
Bus Time
<select name="departtime">
<option value="915">9:15PM</option>
<option value="930">9:30PM</option>
<option value="950">9:50PM</option>
<option value="1010">10:10PM</option>
</select>
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

But only one at a time works (if both female and yes to bus is selected, it hides the first one)

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery isn't a language.  It's a library for Javascript, which is what you're actually writing.

Comment: local variables are your friend. don't reach into the DOM multiple times, grab the element and cache it in a variable. saves on readability and size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two different function names, as declaring the second one will overwrite the first.  Change the name to something more declarative (say, `toggleGender`)  See my change [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/somekittens/6HT2x/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your functions have the name *toggle()*. You will either need to rename them or recode them to allow them to dynamically deal with variables:

Renaming would be:

```
 function toggleMale(value){
 ...
 function toggleFemale(value){
```

The better solution would be making the function dynamic, such as:

```
function toggle(block, value) {
   if(value=='show') { 
      document.getElementById(block).style.display='block';
   }
   else {
      document.getElementById(block).style.display='none';
   }
}
```

This would be called with:

```
onclick="toggle('busblock', 'show');"
```

Or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are defining two JS function with same name so only the last one will work.
2. I can't see you code any jQuery there, you are just using Javascript